# Checking available data from 1 table to another table Laravel 7

Tags: php, html, laravel, function, if-statement

How to check if 1 data from a table is available from another table , i use this kind of `if` function and cant be checked

This is to get the id from table

```html
$getTasRajut = DB::table('tasRajut')->where('id_tas',$getTas)->first();
$getIdTasCart = DB::table('temp_cart')->where('id_user',$getUser) >select('id_tas')->get();
$getIdTasRajut = DB::table('tasRajut')->where('id_tas',$getTas)->get();
```

and this is my checking function

```html
 if($getIdTasCart===$getIdTasRajut){
            return redirect('/store')->with('fail','Tas Rajut sudah ada di keranjang!!');
        }else{
            $insertCart = DB::table('temp_cart')->insert([
                'nama_kostumer' => $getKostumer->nama_kostumer,
                'id_user' => $getKostumer->id_user,
                'nama_tas' => $getTasRajut->nama_tas,
                'harga_tas' => $getTasRajut->harga_tas,
                'gambar_tas' => $getTasRajut->gambar_tas,
                'id_tas' => $getTasRajut->id_tas
            ]);
            return redirect('/store')->with('success','Berhasil dimasukkan ke cart!');
        }
```

I want to check if data from `$getIdTasCart` is available from `$getIdTasRajut`

Thank you

Comment: Though your question is not very clear.  But from the code you wrote above, the if part won't work because you are using get(). If you must use get() then you have to loop through the data before comparing.

Comment: I understand none of code you provided.  However, if you do a one to many relationship on the model all of your code is basically obsolete. Because, you will do a with() and if that user has something in the other table that will be returned, if they do not have anything it will be NULL.